# como acceder a una funcion en otro formulario c#

Tags: c#, formularios, funcion

Muy buenas, actualmente estoy iniciando con c#, previamente usaba Vb, estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto, en el cree un elemento de clase con la intención de utilizarlo como un elemento de modulo en vb y llamar desde allí funciones que utilizare seguido.

En este punto estoy intentando realizar la conexión a la base de datos y mostrar un grid que se encuentra en el form estudiantes utilizando el elemento de clase llamado funciones este es el fragmento de código de estudiantes.

```
        public Funciones funcion;
        public string sql = "SELECT Id, nombre, apellido FROM estudiantes";

        public Estudiantes(){
            InitializeComponent();
            funcion.rellenargrid(sql);
        }
```

este es el código del elemento clase donde esta la función

```
        public SqlConnection conexion;
        public Estudiantes estudiantes;

        public void abrirconexion(){
            conexion = new SqlConnection ( "server=JOSE-PC;database=PSMsistem;integrated security=true"); 
            conexion.Open();
        }

        public void rellenargrid(string sql)
        {
            abrirconexion();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion);
            System.Data.DataTable ds = new System.Data.DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
            estudiantes.gridestudiantes.DataSource=ds;
        }
```

todo esto me genera el siguiente código de error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

funcion fue null.

para cerciorarme que el código funcionaba primero lo había escrito en el mismo formulario como prueba

Comment: Deberias eliminar el simbolo = que se encuentra justo despues del SELECT, asegurate de haber inicializado 'funcion' antes de haber llamado al metodo 'rellenarGrid'

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ lo del signo = lo solucione después que puse la pregunta, por error lo coloque. sin embargo lo que comentas de inicializar 'funcion' me interesa, como se hace eso ?

Comment: por qué no instancias el objeto de la clase y mandas a llamar a la función que quieres

Comment: ¿Alguna vez instancias la clase `Estudiantes` y la asignas a la variable `estudiantes`?

Comment: @HéctorM. como instancio la clase ? te refieres de esta forma ` public Estudiantes estudiantes = new Estudiantes () `

Comment: Sí, esa es una forma válida de hacerlo. Aunque yo me refería a que la instancies como instancias la clase `SqlConnection`, dentro del método `abrirConexion`.